# Oracle - sql - date difference - as per column value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have below table,

| ID | start_date | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 07-JUN-21 03.13.44.4490000 | Initial_Stage |
| 77 | 08-JUN-21 06.28.14.0000000 | Initial_Stage |
| 77 | 08-JUN-21 07.28.14.0000000 | Middle_Stage |
| 77 | 09-JUN-21 06.28.14.0000000 | Final_Stage |

Required output:

As per ID need to find total days to reach Final stage. In case for an ID there is no Final_Stage, then the result will be '0'. If there is Final Stage available for an ID, then need to difference days between Final_Stage to Initial_Stage"

| ID | Start_to_Final_Stage_Days |
| --- | --- |
| 56 | 0 |
| 77 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***MIN***[*IMUM*] aggregation within conditionals considering `Final_Stage` is sorted on top in alphabetical order among stages along with `EXTRACT()` function in order to convert ***interval day to second*** to ***integer*** such as

```sql
SELECT ID, 
       DECODE( MIN(stage), 'Final_Stage', 
               EXTRACT(DAY FROM MIN( CASE WHEN stage = 'Final_Stage' THEN start_date END ) -
                                MIN( CASE WHEN stage = 'Initial_Stage' THEN start_date END) ),0)
           AS "Start_to_Final_Stage_Days"                               
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ID 
 ORDER BY ID;
```

| ID | Start_to_Final_Stage_Days |
| --- | --- |
| 56 | 0 |
| 77 | 1 |

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c81f52501ecc7e49047dab6e8f75d26)</kbd>